# What is this training dummy used for?

Tags: shadow-tactics-blades-of-the-shogun

In the first level of Shadow Tactics: Blades of the Shogun, there's an item highlighted in the pictures below

[image: Screenshot of the strange item from the default camera angle]
[image: Screenshot of the strange item from a different angle]

To me it looks like some kind of training dummy, but I can't interact with it in any way. What can it be used for?

Comment: As someone who's seen way too many martial arts movies, that's definitely a training dummy. No idea why it can be highlighted but not interacted with though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mugen can interact with these dummies by chopping them in half. This appears to serve no practical purpose whatsoever.